# Globalization: Inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, globalization

I wanted to make my MVC3 project Globalization. I have added Multi.resx:

```
  <data name="RegistrationForm" xml:space="preserve">
    <value>Registration Form</value>
  </data>
```

I wrote below code to the view:

@Multi.RegistrationForm

But I am getting **CS0122: 'WAD_CW.MultiResources.Multi' is inaccessible due to its protection level** error

Thank you in advance

Comment: Open your ***.resx** file in design view.
In the drop down called **Access Modifier** change from **internal** to **public**.

Comment: @MatijaGrcic your answer exemplifies the reason I <3 StackOverflow :-)